# Databases - Why case insensitive?

Tags: database, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I saw one or two threads talking globally about case sensitivity, but my question is more specific.

I understand the interest of case insensitive searches on text values for example.

But why would we use case-insensitive database names, tables and columns?

Isn't it going to lead to mistakes? Script languages that use databases are all case-sensitive, so for example if we didn't use the right case for a field it will not be found...

Comment: More often than not, the language used to access the database will use _strings_, not language constructs such as methods or properties.

Comment: I personally always use associative arrays for reading fetched rows from the db, and without being methods nor properties they are case sensitive

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [SQL:2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2008) and [SQL-99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:1999) standards define databases to be case-insensitive for identifiers unless they are quoted.  I've found most [ORMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) will quote identifiers in the SQL they generate.

However, as you probably know not all relational databases strictly adhere to the standards.  DB2 and Oracle are 100% compliant.  PostgreSQL is mostly compliant, except for the fact that it automatically lowercases anything that isn't quoted (which personally I prefer.)

mySQL gets a bit weird, since it stores each table as a file on the file system.  For this reason, it's subject to the case sensitivity of the file system.  On Windows:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO (a INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE 'Foo' (a INTEGER); -- Errors out, already exists
```

Where-as on Linux:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO (a INTEGER); -- Creates FOO table
CREATE TABLE 'Foo' (a INTEGER); -- Creates Foo table
```

SQL Server is even stranger.  It will preserve the case on creation, however let you refer to it in any way after (even if you quote the name!)  You can't create two tables whose only difference is their casing.  Note: SQL Server does have configuration options that control this stuff though, as case-sensitivity of identifiers [will depend on](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188686%28SQL.90%29.aspx) the default collation of the database instance.  How confusing!

While for the most part I agree with you that *computers* (programming languages, databases, file systems, URLs, passwords, etc) should be case-sensitive, all systems are implemented independently and may or may not adhere to standards that may or may not exist.  Implementing a case-senstive database is definitely possible, if you know the ins and outs of your particular database system and how it behaves.

It's really *your* responsibility to implement *your* system in a way that works for *you*, and not the entire technology industry to implement everything in a consistent way to make your life easier.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I was asking in a best practice approch. Because I'm not still the only one responsible of the programs/services that I use. This reinforces my idea of telling people to use case sensitive settings.

Comment: Also I didn't know about the auto lower case of postGre. I like this idea too.

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY - Postgres has been my database of choice for some time now.  I just love it.

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage of using case sensitivity is that when we deploy it on the client site, our DB works regardless whether the client's SQL Server is set up case sensitive or not, so yes it really isn't a good idea and I don't know why anyone would use case-insensitve database tables/columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you would redo all the it industry today, with the knowledge and technology you might default to do everything case sensitive with the only exception of things especially asked for being not case sensitive.

But back in the days before I was born and even when I started working (ok, playing) with computers many computers couldn't even differentiate between upper and lower case letters. I build a might complicated card to plug into my fake apple II to make it understand the difference.

So I guess in these days having something like a difference between upper and lower case was something like having a retina display nowadays. Its cool if you have it. And in 10 years we might ask why anybody ever created an application without such displays in mind, but today it just isn't that relevant.

Same is true for databases (and file systems) since many of them and their respective standards go back to the 70s at least.

Comment: I would have said that old systems (already based on ascii tables even 7bits) should begin without knowing the relation between x and X or y and Y...