# How to make log-in form a case sensitive in C#?

Tags: c#, oop

Could somebody help me with my problem on my log-in form?

My username registered on the database is "admin" (all are in lowercase form). However, upon logging-in with username, "admiN" (considering N is capitalized), I still get logged-in successfully.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Account account = new Account();

    if (txtUserName.Text == "" || txtPassword.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Empty Fields Detected ! Please fill up all the fields");
        return;
    }

    if (account.Authorize(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text))
    {
            MessageBox.Show("Login Successfully!");
            this.Hide();
            main.showMeForm4(this);
    }
    else
    {
        txtPassword.Focus();
        MessageBox.Show("Username or Password Is Incorrect");
        txtUserName.Text = "";
        txtPassword.Text = "";
    }
}

//class Account
    public bool Authorize(string userName, string userPassword)
            {
                Connection connection = new Connection();
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Account WHERE Username=@userName and Password=@userPassword";
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection.ConnectionString);
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userPassword", userPassword);
                conn.Open();
                MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (login.Read())
                {
                    conn.Close();
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    conn.Close();
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: You need to update your database to be case sensitive (most are case insensitive).  Check this out:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076995/databases-why-case-insensitive

Comment: Most people agree that usernames shouldn't be case sensitive but (of course) passwords should be. Do you really want `admin`, `admIn` and `Admin` as three viable names for *separate* accounts?

Comment: Yeah, case sensitive usernames is a bad idea. You shouldn’t care about casing for a username, passwords however should be case sensitive

Comment: @Brad: your link is about database tables & column names being case-sensitive - not the content of each field.

Comment: Can you post your `Account` class file? Particularly the `Authorize` method?

Comment: Oh dear. Plain text passwords saved in the database. Any reason you are writing this yourself and not using a one of many authentication frameworks available for ASP.Net?

Comment: If you must do this yourself, .NET has a built-in implementation of PBKDF2 you can use. You should store password hashes in the database, read those based on the user ID and then run a PBKDF2-comparison of the entered password and the hash.

Comment: You should be comparing hashes anyway.. not actual passwords. Hashes will be different based on case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want by doing the comparison in C# (instead of SQL) since string comparisons are case sensitive in C#:

```
MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (login.Read())
            {
                var  userNameFromDb = login["Username"].ToString();
                var  passwordFromDb = login["Password"].ToString();

                conn.Close();
                return userNameFromDb == userName && passwordFromDb  == userPassword
            }
```

That being said, if this is for a something more than just your personal use / learning, I would recommend you reconsider how you are storing passwords. Right now, it looks like you're storing them in clear text which is a huge security risk. You should look into hashing and salting passwords and use a pre-made framework for authorization / authentication.

Also, I agree with other commenters that probably want to ignore case for the username.

Answer (score 2):

Your query will not take case into account. (default SQL Server behavior)

`SELECT * FROM tbl_Account WHERE Username=@userName and Password=@userPassword`

You can change your query to

`SELECT * FROM tbl_Account
WHERE Username=@userName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
AND Password=@userPassword COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`

By changing the collation, it will take into account the case.